# Woocommerce, Create account only if the payment is successfully completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, registration, checkout

The registration form is enabled in checkout page.

When a user fills the form and  clicks the button to proceed to paiement, his account is automatically created even if he didn't paid.

Is there a way to create a user account only after completing the payment?

Comment: yes you can, but not that simple that can be answered here. Maybe try it yourself first then get back here to a smaller specific part of code where you are stuck.